# Keycloak / Docker Mac OS - CI runtime exec failed: exec failed

Tags: docker, keycloak

I'm trying to spin up Keycloak running on Docker, using Mac OS.

I am following the guide [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/), opting for the Postgres image.

```
docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=keycloak -e POSTGRES_USER=keycloak -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d postgres
```

The guide (above) then advises to create an admin user, I must run...

```
docker exec <CONTAINER> keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD>
```

However I am getting the following error in my terminal.....

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting 
container process caused "exec: \"keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh\": stat
keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like you are running the create admin user command in `postgres` container, which doesn't have the `add-user-keycloak.sh` script. In order to create the user you need to run the command against `keycloak` container or just launch it initially with credentials and skip the user creation steps as:

```
docker run -e KEYCLOAK_USER=<USERNAME> -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD> jboss/keycloak
```

Comment: Of course yes! I think it's time to take a break for 10 minutes :) Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Perfect. Happy to help! :)